# Why is my React client folder not accessible on Github?

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I was able to successfully push my React client/server folders and files to Github, but the client folder is not clickable and has an arrow on the folder icon. I used the following commands to initially push the folders, then attempted to re-upload the client folder:

```
% git init
% git add .
% git commit -m MESSAGE
% git commit add origin URL
% git push -u origin master

*** Everything successfully loads, but client folder is inaccessible ***

% git rm --cached client
% git commit -m MESSAGE
% git add .
% git commit -m MESSAGE
% git push

*** Client folder is added back, but still not clickable/accessible ***
```

Comment: You made a *submodule* (perhaps what I sometimes call a "half-assed" one, lacking the `.gitmodules` information needed to *clone* the submodule). If you don't want a submodule, don't try to add a Git repository to a Git repository. If you *do* want a submodule, just make sure it's a fully-assed one, using `git submodule add`. I can't answer whether you do or do not want a submodule.

Comment: Ah, so it sounds like this module is getting generated as a part of my  `% npx create-react-app` command? Interesting. In that case, I would probably choose to simply delete the submodule, assuming that doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: Probably, yes. I don't actually use npx (I have used npm, though never written my own stuff using it, at a previous job, but not npx) but if it creates a (nested) repository, that would do it.